# Does MySQL 5.6 support 3D Points?

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, geodjango

Recently I've been trying to migrate from sqlite to MySQL 5.6 (5.7 had problems with GIS fields). I realized that none of my 3D Points have been imported into the MySQL database so I went in and manually tried to update rows with Django dumpdata output but apparently it doesn't accept 3d points and doesn't give any warnings or errors.

Should I switch to another database system? Am I doing something wrong?

```
mysql> UPDATE entrance SET location=GeomFromText("POINT Z (32.077624 36.58562 123)") WHERE id=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE entrance SET location=GeomFromText("POINT(32.077624 36.58562)") WHERE id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM entrance;
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          
|
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
...
| location                  | point        | YES  |     | NULL    |           
...
```